# Recipient is Unable to Open Attachments where Email Attachment is sent from database,

Tags: php, email, attachment

previously should I use an exact  file name and file type, I am able to send the email and being able to open the file. However, should I get the name of the file from the database, I am able to send the email with the document with the correct file name (and type) but unable to open the file.

```
        $to = "$email"; //Recipient Email Address
        $subject = "$subject"; //Email Subject
        $headers = "From: example@example.com\r\nReply-To: example@example.com";
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\"";

        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('resume/$fileName'))); // Set your file path here
//define the body of the message.

        $message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the html message.
        $message .= $content;
        $message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";

//include attachment
        $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n" . "Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"$fileName\"\r\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= $attachment;
        $message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

//send the email
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

$fileName is a variable getting the file name from the database.

Comment: *"However, should I get the name of the file from the database"* - There's no DB code here.

Comment: Use `file_get_contents("resume/$fileName")` instead of `file_get_contents('resume/$fileName')`

Comment: This btw `$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";` should read as `$message .= "\r\n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";`

Comment: How do the generated messages' sources differ?

Comment: @TBI THANKS SO MUCH! The changing of the different type of quote works!